# asp:Gridview & asp:Table generated border="0" property in > .NET4.0

Tags: asp.net, controls, validation

I understand this is an issue that has been fixed in .NET 4.0+ however, upgrading our framework is not an option as of yet. SOON, but not yet. For the time being I am using .NET 3.5.

As I've seen in many other posts that this is a very common issue. Nobody really seems to say why it is an issue, which is why it seems like many answers don't seem to grasp the actual problem.

When using asp:Table control or asp:GridView control, the generated mark-up looks as such:

```
<asp:Table id="table1" border="0" runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

Gridview is much the same but includes a 'rules' attribute that can be ommitted by setting the Gridlines property to "none". However, while setting gridlines to none takes care of the rules attribute, the border="0" always remains.

**Now the problem**: in order to Validate this code using W3 validator, the border property MUST be set to border="" OR border="1". This seems like a very simple fix, further investigation proves quite the contrary.

I've tried to change the value to something the validator will accept:

ie:

```
table1.Attributes.Add("border", "1"); // This generates <asp:Table id="table1" border="0" border="1" runat="server"></asp:Table>

table1.Attributes.Add("border", null); // This generates <asp:Table id="table1" border="0" border="" runat="server"></asp:Table>

table1.Attributes["border"] = "1";  // This generates <asp:Table id="table1" border="0" border="1" runat="server"></asp:Table>

table1.Attributes["border"] = "";  // This generates <asp:Table id="table1" border="0" border="" runat="server"></asp:Table>

table1.Attributes.Remove("border"); // This generates <asp:Table id="table1" border="0"  runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

None of these have reached the desired result. asp:Table always generates border="0" and I can't seem to modify the value.

Does anyone have any other ideas, and again, upgrading the framework is not an option for the time being. We will be upgrading at some point in the relatively near future - but not before this version goes to production.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked into this issue for quite a while and nothing I read on the Internet could fix this issue and even the Framework 4.0 recommended ideas weren't working since my application was already targetting the Framework 4.0 and still, couldn't remove that "Border=0" from the GridView control. What I've found out though is that my Web.Config, though was targetting the Framework 4.0 also had controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion set to "3.5" on the Pages tag. By removing this setting, it automatically got rid of the "Border" attribute from the GridView control.

Comment: Thanks for replying, removing controlRederingCompatibilityVersion entirely is what fixed it for us as well.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to do this by tapping into the GridView's RowDataBound event, for example:

```
protected void MyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
     {
         tc.Attributes["style"] = "border: 1px solid #ccc"; 
     }
}
```

With the GridView, the declarative border attribute adds an inline style declaration which only applies to the table itself, not individual cells.

Adding the border attribute programmatically does not use an inline style, but uses the HTML border property, which browsers apply to ALL borders inside the table.

One more thing, if you are using Eric Meyer's reset, it breaks the table rendering in the GridView. Solution to that particular issue is to remove all table elements from the reset rule. This might account for the table itself not playing nice for you.

Comment: Thanks but this adds the attribute to each cell of the table. Has no effect on the generated `<table tabindex="1" border="0" id="ctl00_ContentMain_ctlSearchResults_dvSearchResult" style="width:99%;">`

Comment: Check for any resets in your CSS; this is known to break the styling for tables.

Comment: Also, try adding the rule for the table in the RowDataBound handler instead.

Comment: Attempted adding the rule for table instead, and it's the same issue. Adds the new border:1px to the style attribute, while persisting the problematic border="0" attribute. `<table tabindex="1" border="0" id="ctl00_ContentMain_ctlSearchResults_dvSearchResult" style="width:99%;border: 1px">`
Doesn't seem to be a styling issue, more an issue of not being able to remove the border attribute or even modify it's value.

Comment: It seems the only way to set border="1" is by adding back the rules attribute, which itself will not pass validation. Catch 22... Any other ideas?

Comment: Update: the only way to fix this is by setting `<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />` in web.config and setting your ASP.NET version in your IIS virtual directory to 4.0.30319. This is not a CSS issue. See: http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2010/03/03/ASPNET-Part-9-Rendering-Cleaner-HTML.aspx. While this is no help to me until I can upgrade to 4.0, short of creating a custom control, I'm confident in saying this is the only fix for this issue. Thanks for your help IrishChieftain

Answer (score 0):

In code behind added the below code it will work.

```
gridview1.Attributes.Remove("border");
```

or

```
gridview1.GridLines = GridLines.None;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

in my case, working with a team project with many different design parts, the best solution founded so far was to use jQuery to remove the attribute border from the table, this procedure wont mess up with the way other components render in different areas of the web app and will let the page pass html validation test.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">$('#TableID').removeAttr("border");</script>
```

Of course this is a "on page" solution. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `GridLines="None"` to your gridview. It will remove border attribute.

Welcome.